# Factor the binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time getting to factor this binomial: I have tried other methods but they do not seem to work... ah well.
$$4m^2-\frac{9}{25}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: $(2m)^2-(\frac{3}{5})^2$

Comment: If you're still stuck, try multiplying out $(4x - \frac{2}{3})(4x + \frac{2}{3})$ and focus on how the final answer of that calculation resembles your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $4m^2-\frac{9}{25}$, note that the second term is $(\frac{3}{5})^2$ and you have a difference of squares.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is homework, so only ideas from me here.

Note that the formula is of the form $A^2-B^2$.

and we know that $A^2-B^2$ can be factored easily.

Comment: If I do that, I get 4m^2-9/25... errr.... wha

Comment: weka, what exactly is the problem? $4m^2 = A^2$, so $A = 2m$...